# Why does storing values at non-32 multiple memory locations spill over to next location?

Tags: solidity, assembly, yul

Take this line for example (Yul):

```
mstore(0x24, 0x0443455243)
```

If it was `mstore(0x20, 0x0443455243)`, then the entire value would have been stored at location `0x20`.

However, if `0x24` is used, I'd expect the value to be stored at `0x24`, but **only the first byte is stored at `0x20`, whereas the next 4 bytes spill over and get stored at the end of location `0x40`.**

[image: Debugging in Remix shows what gets stored where]

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

I think it works exactly as described by the [EVM bytecode MSTORE](https://ethervm.io/#52):

- `MSTORE (uint256 offset, uint256 value) -> memory[offset:offset+32] = value`
- EVM uses big-endian, your value is 0x0443455243 = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000443455243
- So memory[0x24:0x24+0x20 (32)] = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000443455243
- Notice that your data has 27 (0x1B) leading zero bytes => the first byte (`0x04`) will be at address : `0x24 + 0x1B = 0x3F`
- So the layout will be `0x20: 00`, `0x21: 00` ... `0x3F: 04`, `0x40: 43`, `0x41: 45`, `0x42: 52`, `0x43: 43`

Answer (score 0):

`mstore` always 32 bytes of word hence `0x0443455243` will be added a zero padding to make it 32 bytes.

Memory is like an array, you can access and store at any point *(as long as you have enough gas)*. Even though remix show it as `0x0` block, `0x20` in block, it is just a sequence of numbers, following image of memory gives a better view

[image: Image 1]

As it is like a sequence of numbers *(unlike storage - which can be allocated with 32 bytes words in a given slot)*, you can start writing from anywhere.

In the above example, I have added a 32 bytes word and 5 bytes word to the memory in different indexes.

If you execute the following opcodes in a transaction it would look like the following

```
push1 0x24
mload

(or mload 0x24)
```

[image: Image 3]

memory allocation is always of 32 bytes or multiples of it.
If you want 1 byte in **fresh** memory it will allocate 32 bytes, similarly 33 bytes will get an allocation till 0x40th index *(64 bytes of allocation of memory in full)*. In your case you are trying to store a 32 bytes value in the memory slot `0x24` *(index 36)*. Which means the storing start at the index 0x24 and spreads till 0x44*(68 index)*. As Memory is allocated in 32 bytes of word from `0x44`*(index 68)* - `0x60`*(index 96)* will be filled up with zeros.

if you want only to use up to 0x40 you can do a several `mstore8` opcodes instead. note that `mstore8` also costs 3 gas same as `mstore`(with no [memory expansion](https://www.evm.codes/about#memoryexpansion))